# Counting sort a list in descending order

Tags: python, python-3.x

So basically I want to figure out how to reverse a counting sort. This is the code I found:

```
def countingSort(myList):
    maxValue = 0
    for i in range(len(myList)):
        if myList[i] > maxValue:
            maxValue = myList[i]

    buckets = [0] * (maxValue + 1)

    for i in myList:
        buckets[i] += 1

    i = 0
    for j in range(maxValue + 1):
         for a in range(buckets[j]):
             myList[i] = j
             i += 1

    return myList

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sortedList = countingSort([1,23,4,5,6,7,8])
    print(sortedList)
```

So I decided to change line 16 to this:

```
i -= 1
```

The results are very close, but I get this:

```
[1, 23, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4]
```

My issue is that 1 is before 23 for some reason. I tried reverting some of the other signs, but it usually results in an out of bounds error. Any ways to work around it?

Comment: Can't you just use `sorted` function or `.sort` method?

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: @MarkMeyer eh, basically, most of the introductory CS material, the intro-to-programming stuff, was all created with languages like C or Java, where you are working with primitive arrays and C-style for-loops. Most of the education AFAIKT is just Java in Python. Unfortunate.

Answer (score 2):

Reverse the range that `j` iterates through so you start from high numbers then end with low numbers:

```py
for j in range(maxValue, -1, -1):
```

Comment: *or* the more readable (IMO) `reversed(range(maxValue + 1))`

Comment: These are correct, but you'll need `i += 1` so it doesn't loop around backwards again, or you'll get `[23, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`

Answer (score 0):

With `i -= 1` you're writing at indices 0, -1, -2, -3 etc. That is, you write the smallest number (the 1) at the front, and then the remaining numbers from the back backwards. You can make it work by starting with `i = -1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int j=largest;
    for(int i=0;i<count.length;i++){
        while(count[i]>n){
            arr[j] = i;
            j--;
            count[i]++;
```

use this in case of reversing an array for counting sort